# SQL Server help - PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table #rah that contains only two columns 
(customer id and product)

Table values

```
product       customer id
PD        100045592
PD        100030983
PD        210330909
PDRU          200067524
PDRM          210007421
```

Does anyone know the best way I can use the PIVOT function in SQL Server 2008 to write this?

Desired output:

```
Product  Count
PD        3
PDRU      1
PDRM      1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the PIVOT function for this. You can easily get this result by using an aggregate function and a GROUP BY:

```
select product, count(customer_id) Total
from yourtable
group by product;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dd261/1). This gives a result:

```
| PRODUCT | TOTAL |
-------------------
|      PD |     3 |
|    PDRM |     1 |
|    PDRU |     1 |
```

If you wanted the `product` names as columns, then you could use PIVOT:

```
select PD, PDRU, PDRM
from yourtable
pivot
(
  count(customer_id)
  for product in(PD, PDRU, PDRM)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dd261/2). The pivot gives a result:

```
| PD | PDRU | PDRM |
--------------------
|  3 |    1 |    1 |
```

Comment: Would PIVOT be a good use if there were 3 columns in the table?

Comment: @ShawnRahmani The PIVOT function is used to convert data from rows into columns.  So if you wanted the product names as column headers, then you would use PIVOT -- see this demo --http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dd261/2